# How to analyse junit test results

Tags: unit-testing, testing, netbeans, junit

I have a set of test cases, for which I need to demonstrate an analysis. Is there a plugin or any other way to analyse test results?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for ONLY Netbeans IDE plugin or any other libraries ?

Comment: Anything is fine. I simply want a way to graphically represent an analysis of the test cases I already have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Cobertura Maven Plugin** for **analysing and code coverage reports on the unit tests**.

You can refer the below links for more details on Cobertura Maven Plugin:

http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/

https://www.mkyong.com/qa/maven-cobertura-code-coverage-example/

For Netbeans, you can refer tikione-jacocoverage plugin from below link:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48570/tikione-jacocoverage